# How can I break locks in Two Worlds II?

Tags: two-worlds-2

I know about picking and auto-picking. The game shows "break lock: 50% damage weapon: 0%" when I approach a lock with my weapons drawn. How can I try and break them? If I attack, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stand in front of the lock and hit it. This works best if you first enter the lockpicking screen to position yourself. Note that doing this has a chance to damage or even destroy (master locks) your weapon.